# Inherit C++ class from protobuf

Tags: c++, inheritance, protocol-buffers

I have objects of two types: TActionInfo and TActionStats. The first one describes action's characteristics and the second one can "eat" the first one and maintain some statistics based on many actions.

It is very convenient to use a protobuf in my task, because these objects are frequently serialized and deserialized.

It seems to be a good idea that TActionStats should have a method like

```
bool AddAction(const TActionInfo& action);
```

Is it a good idea to inherit a class from from google-protobuf TActionStats class?
 It is a good idea to inherit smth from protobuf in general?

Comment: I would prefer to have interned protobuf class member variables instead of inheriting them. In (even more) general, IMHO it's the better idea to avoid inheritance as much as possible. It's rare i can answer the question _"Is a?"_ with yes.

Comment: Design is *sometimes* a matter of taste. Anyway, I try to avoid class names like `...Info`, `...Stats`, or `...Data`. When I'm tempted to create such a class, I ask myself: Why doesn't the *real* class (say `TAction`) contain its info and stats? And if I really just want some class that just keeps the info about another class instance, how can I avoid mixing layers of abstraction? Look, you have a method `AddAction` but what you really add is action info. Layers mixed. Isn't it the action you want to add here? Also consider [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you should not subclass protobuf types.

Consider what would happen if you embedded a `TActionStats` inside some other message type:

```
message TEnvelope {
  optional TActionStats stats = 0;
  optional string recipient = 1;
}
```

Now when you call `stats()` or `mutable_stats()` on a `TEnvelope`, you will receive a `TActionStats`, not your subclass. If you have a bunch of code that expects specifically to receive your subclass, you won't be able to call that code (without making a copy), so now you have to rewrite everything.

Instead, write your helper methods as independent, free-standing functions.